# Exception when calling IDbgConsole.PrintTextToConsole in a WinDbg Extension

Tags: c#, windbg

I am trying to write a windbbg extension in C#. The extension is only a very basic and should simply print a statement to the console however when I load the extension and run the command I get the below error:

```
0:005> !testCommand
e0434352 Exception in C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Dbg\EngineExtensions\WinDbgExtension.dll.testCommand debugger extension.
      PC: 00007ffe`42183b29  VA: 00000000`00000000  R/W: 80070002  Parameter: 00000000`00000000
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using DbgX.Interfaces;
using DbgX.Interfaces.Enums;
using DbgX.Interfaces.Listeners;
using DbgX.Interfaces.Services;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace WindbgExt
{
    public class Extension
    {

        [Import]
        private static IDbgConsole _console;

        [DllExport("testCommand")]
        public static void testCommand(IntPtr client, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string args)
        {
            _console.PrintTextToConsole("This worked");
        }

        [DllExport("DebugExtensionInitialize")]
        public static int DebugExtensionInitialize(ref uint version, ref uint flags)
        {
            version = DEBUG_EXTENSION_VERSION(1, 0);
            flags = 0;
            return 0;
        }

        private static uint DEBUG_EXTENSION_VERSION(uint Major, uint Minor) => ((Major & 0xffff) << 16) | (Minor & 0xffff);
    }
}
```

WinDbg recognizes the extension and the command. However I don't know what this error means or what could be causing it. Any help identifying what is causing the error would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
After reading some of the comments I did some testing and commenting out the line `_console.PrintTextToConsole("This worked");` stops the error being thrown. I expect the issue is in how the interface is declared but I don't know how to rectify it. I have tried setting the class and interface as static however this has not rectified the situation.

**EDIT 2:**
I have now tried declaring an instance of IDbgConsole and calling PrintTextToConsole in every way I can think of however all of them generate the below error. Even wrapping it in a try and catch block does not help as the catch section is not triggered. If there is another way of writing to the console that would be easier than fixing this error that would also work as a solution.

Comment: Can you run the command again, like twice in a row? Which WinDbg version are you using? They changed the interface and AFAIK, it's quite common for extensions to fail on the first command.

Comment: @TheGeneral: why remove all the using statements? IMHO these are good for reproducibility, i.e. if I want to actually compile the code. I'm frustrated by all SO answers that omit using/import statements, because it's often not trivial to figure out what it needs.

Comment: Are you sure `_console` has been resolved correctly and is != null?

Comment: @KlausGütter: IMHO, a NullReferenceException would be mapped to an AccessViolation and it would no longer be a e0434352, but c0000005.

Comment: Hi Thomas, the `using RGiesecke.DllExport;` instructs the compiler to generate unmanaged code as oppose to the managed MSIL code the C# compiler normally produces. Also running the command twice in a row produced the same error each time,

Comment: Hi Klaus, if I comment out the _console declaration it no longer throws an error. I still need to use this method however so I'm not sure how to rectify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing two concepts here. There are two kind of Windbg extensions: the debugger extensions and the UI extensions.

- The UI extensions are loaded automatically by the WPF shell (assuming you put them in the right folder). I wrote [a few articles about them](https://labs.criteo.com/2017/09/extending-new-windbg-part-1-buttons-commands/) but the API is still undocumented. With UI extensions, you can use MEF and services such as `IDbgConsole`, but you can't directly interact with the debugger (you have to find the right service and use it to send commands)
- The debugger extensions are loaded in a separate process. They're loaded with the `.load` or `.loadby` command. They allow you to interact directly with the debugging engine. With those extensions, you can expose new commands if you use a native export tool, such as `RGiesecke.DllExport`. What is important to understand is that they run in a separate process and are completely isolated from the UI. **You can't use MEF and services such as `IDbgConsole` from there.**

In your case, it seems you're just trying to print stuff to the console. You can do so by using the `IDebugControl` object. It's easier to write a stream that wraps it and set it as the console output stream, so you can just use `Console.WriteLine`. There's an example of how to do so on the ClrMD github repository (that the `DbgEngStream` class): https://github.com/microsoft/clrmd/blob/18c9e1304228d375191b5f805b7a5d9da2ec86ef/src/Samples/WindbgExtension/Common.cs